# How to make columns goes below when i fill "ket2" with data that exceeds its box design?

Tags: crystal-reports

i will explains more information in the images, sorry for bad english.
"i want to make everything that belows the red line goes below if i fill this "ket2" with words that exceeds its box size (can grow).So, the words and box betweens red lines (upside and downside) didnt crash/collisions. Thanks for answering my question, im newbie on CR. I'm using Crystal Report 8.5 btw.
[Crystal report design ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NPexR.jpg)

Comment: I would help but I am confused as to what you are asking.  What is 'Ket2'? What exactly needs to be pushed below red line if 'ket2' exceeds its box size?

Comment: @AleksandarZoric ket2 is a data from my database access (you can fill with words/ longtext), and when i fill ket2 with words that exceeds its box size, it will push everything below red line, SS http://puu.sh/BGqQQ/55d72a9241.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Split your "details b" section in two. Then, you will have "details
   b" and "details c".
2. Keep "ket2" and its siblings in "details b" section.
3. Put the below-the-red-line-fields in "details c" section.
4. Right click "ket2", choose "format object", and check "can grow".

Comment: i will try this today, im outside now, thanks for answering, i will mention again if this will work/not

Comment: any idea how to make detail b and detail c to be on the same page (with table lines too) ? it works but the data below red line is on different pages.

Comment: check if: (1) it has enough space to be in the same page; (2) if the option "new page before" is checked in "details b" section properties (it should not be marked). If it is ok, post a screenshot of the report with the page break so that i can verify if i am understanding you correctly.

Comment: it seems i just need to make a new section and suppress blank section per columns to do that. i realized after checked back your 1st and 2nd comments. Thanks for yor great help sir, and i cant upvote since my rep still <15.

Comment: sorry for OOT, but im new to Crystal Report and im using 8.5 version. (1) Is crystal report still good these day? not obsolete? (2) What is pro and cons between CS 8.5 and integrated one on VB.NET 2010? i find the CS 8.5 tools are more complete than integrated one or u need to setting the tools on integrated one so it will show complete set of the tools?

Comment: @Ricky Limanto, to answer your question - right click on the detail section on the left and check 'underlay following section'.  Doing so will overlay detail A with detail B therefore displaying them on the same page.